# Is it possible to get the distance to a star in the IPHAS DR2 catalog?

Tags: distances

I'm looking at the [IPHAS DR2](http://www.iphas.org/dr2/#download) catalog. It has the Right Ascension and Declination but I'm not seeing any distance information (lightyears or parsecs). I'm wondering, given the columns in the dataset, if the distance can be calculated.

Answer (score 2):

Only by knowing what kind of a star it is, or by inferring that information from the available colours. From there you use a photometric or spectroscopic parallax calibration. ie. There is a relationship between the absolute magnitude and colours of a main sequence star. Of course there is no guarantee you are looking at a main sequence star.

You can get more idea by cross correlating with the 2MASS JHK catalogue, as the J-H vs H-K colours of giants are usually distinctive.

More specific help needs a more specific question.